Prove or disprove $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1-\frac{1}{n}}f_n(x) dx=\int_0^1 f(x)dx$ is $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly.
$\{f_n\}$ be sequence of continuous function on $[0,1]$ and $f_n$ converges to f unifomly. Prove or disprove
$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{1-\frac{1}{n}} f_n(x) dx=\int_0^1 f(x) dx$
Any hints will be fine

User3333, if you wrote in your post what you tried, it would be appreciated very much.

Here is an outline of one at to show this: Note that
$$
\begin{split}
\left|\int_0^{1-1/n} f_n(x) dx - \int_0^1 f(x)dx\right| &\leq |\int_{0}^{1-1/n} (f_n-f)(x)dx| +|\int_{1-1/n}^1 f(x)dx|\\
& \leq \int_{0}^{1-1/n} |f_n(x)-f(x)|dx + \int_{1-1/n}^1|f(x)|dx
\end{split}
$$
Thus it is enough to show that each of the two quantities in the second line become arbitrarily small for large enough $n$. For the first, you need to use the fact that $f_n \to f$ uniformly, and for the second term, you need to use the fact that length of the interval you are integrating over tends to zero and $|f(x)|$ is bounded.
Hope that helps!

Please avoid answering no effort questions
